# Trying to write to an existing XML file for C#

Tags: c#, xml

Thank you very much in advance

This is the original XML File

```
<my:Incident>
       <my:Category>This is for Category</my:Category>
              <my:Status>`Status is Close`</my:Status>
       <my:Description>`This is the description part</my:Description>
</my:Incident>
```

and I would like to add other fields under `my:Incident`

This is an example of it:

```
<my:Incident>
       <my:Category>This is for Category</my:Category>
              <my:Status>`Status is Close`</my:Status>
       <my:SummaryDescription>This is the summary</my:SummaryDescription>
       <my:Description>`This is the description part</my:Description>
</my:Incident>
```

I tried to implemented but I got this error message:

> The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.

```
public void writerXMLTest(string fileName)
        {

            if (!File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(fileName, null);
                writer.WriteStartElement("my:Incident");
                writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.Close();
            }

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
            XElement demoNode = new XElement("my:Incident");
            demoNode.Add(new XElement("my:SummaryDescription", "Test Test"));


            Console.WriteLine("I write it!!!!!"); 
        }
```

I would appreciate if anyone can guide me where I did wrong in my code.

---

I modified the code a little. But now I'm not able to write it to the existing XML File

This is my code:

```
public void writerXMLTest(string fileName)
        {

            if (!File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(fileName, null);
                writer.WriteStartElement("Incident", "my");
                writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.Close();
            }

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
            XElement demoNode = new XElement("SummaryDescription", "Test Test");


            Console.WriteLine("I write it!!!!!"); 
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems here. First your "original XML" is not valid because you have not defined the "my" namespace. Either you have not shown us the entire XML file, or you are hand-coding invalid XML. Don't do that.

> I'm not able to write it to the existing XML File.

What does "I'm not able" mean? It throws an exception? What is the exception? Or do you mean your file is unchanged after running your code? That is unsurprising because your code doesn't actually do anything.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
```

This loads your XML file from disk... and then does nothing with it. It doesn't change the file.

```
XElement demoNode = new XElement("SummaryDescription", "Test Test");
```

This creates a new XML element, totally unrelated to `doc`, the original file, or to anything else... and then throws it away without doing anything with it. You have not added it anywhere or saved anything to a file.

> and I would like to add other fields under my:Incident

If you want to add `demoNode` to the file, you first must find the `Incident` node:

```
XElement e = doc.Descendants(XName.Get("Incident", nameSpace)).FirstOrDefault<XElement>();
```

Add your new element to it:

```
if (e != null)
{
    e.Add( new XElement(XName.Get("SummaryDescription", nameSpace), "Test Test") );
}
```

Then save the changed document

```
doc.Save(fileName);
```

Answer (score 5):

This is wrong:

```
 writer.WriteStartElement("my:Incident");
```

This is right:

```
 writer.WriteStartElement("Incident", "blablablaSpace:my");
```

**Edit:**

```
 writer.WriteStartElement("Incident", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2005-09-22T20:42:56:my");
```

Comment: I kind of fix the error but now I'm not able to write it to the existing XML File

Comment: @yyc2001 What does this mean? I hope you didn't use what I wrote literally :)

Comment: @FailedDec Not really I modified my post to show my update code.

Comment: @yyc2001 What is my? Isn't it something like xmlns:my="foo.html.com"

Comment: my is just a namespace in the original XML File. `xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2005-09-22T20:42:56"`

Comment: @FailedDec Thanks. However I'm still not able to write to the file. I'm not sure where did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your "my:" prefix is a namespace. You must use TagName = "Incident", Namespace="my".

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft provides documentation on using XmlTextWriter with namespaces

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfche0ka(v=vs.80).aspx